# create jar and import it in a Java program without IDE

Tags: java, linux

I want to create a Java library without using IDE. The library has to have a package called my_pckg and whithin my_pckg there is the java file that implements two methods (get and set). How do I do this?
After that, I want to use the two methods (get and set) in another java program, by importing my library. How do I import the library?

I have ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create your Java class with 'vim MyClass.java' (or 'emacs', if you're a heathen...).  Compile your Java class with ['javac'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html). Package it with ['jar'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html). Execute it with ['java'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

I'm on Fedora, not Ubuntu, but this should work for you (assuming you have a JDK installed):

```
~/test $ pwd
/home/myname/test
~/test $ vi MyClass.java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
~/test $ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname myname 114 Oct 23 10:20 MyClass.java
~/test $ javac MyClass.java
~/test $ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname myname 414 Oct 23 10:21 MyClass.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname myname 114 Oct 23 10:20 MyClass.java
~/test $ jar cvf MyClass.jar MyClass.class 
added manifest
adding: MyClass.class(in = 414) (out= 285)(deflated 31%)
~/test $ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname myname 414 Oct 23 10:21 MyClass.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname myname 744 Oct 23 10:21 MyClass.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname myname 114 Oct 23 10:20 MyClass.java
~/test $ java -cp ./MyClass.jar MyClass
Hello!
~/test $
```

For more information, "man javac", "man jar", and "man java" are your friends...

Comment: To create the jar, I execute: `jar -cf myJar.jar ./my_pckg/progr.java`. Note that progr.java does not have any main, because it defines and implements the two methods. After that, I compiled the test program (`javac -classpath myJar.jar test.java`) that `import my_pckg.*;` but when I execute the test program `java -classpath myJar.jar test` I get this error `Error: Could not find or load main class test`. Where I am wrong?

Comment: You set your classpath to just the jarfile - so it doesn't find the test.class that is 'here'.  Try `java -cp myJar.jar:.`, to add current-location to your classpath.

Comment: Ok. I have one more problem. In the test program I wrote `import my_pckg.*;` and in the main of the test program I wrote: `progr.get()` but the test does not compile because I get the error `error: cannot find symbol`. How do I fix this? I have also tried with `my_pckg.progr.get()` but does not work.

Comment: Questions to consider: Is 'get()' a method of the 'progr' class that lives in the 'my_pckg' package? How do you get access to an instance of 'progr'? If you don't want get() to require an instance - what's the Java syntax for defining a method on the class, instead of an instance of the class?

Comment: Yes, `get()` is a method of `progr` class that lives in the `my_pckg` package. How do I call  `get()` in `test` java program? Should I import `my_pckg` in `test` program? After that, how do I call `get()`  in `test` program? I tried to call it in this way: `progr.get()` but I got the error `error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I see what's going on. `javac` needs to be able to find anything you're importing in **its** classpath. So, standing in the directory 'above' `my_pckg`, you would issue a command something like `javac -classpath . my_pckg/test.java`, so that javac can find the my_pckg directory and everything in it. Does that help?